# R dplyr perform different aggregation by group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe `dat` which looks like this:

```
   dat <- structure(list(cell.ID = c(329574L, 329574L, 329574L, 329574L, 
    329574L, 329574L, 329574L, 329574L, 329574L, 329574L, 329574L, 
    329574L), Year = c("2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", 
    "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010", "2010"), month_name = c("June", 
    "July", "June", "July", "June", "July", "June", "July", "June", 
    "July", "June", "July"), value = c(459.860986624053, 398.94083733151, 
    16, 23, 111.69, 453.333, 71.55, 30.38, 31.928, 30.13355, 17.587, 
    19.7938709677419), variable_name = c("ETo", "ETo", "Rday", "Rday", 
    "Rsum", "Rsum", "Thdd", "Thdd", "Tmax", "Tmax", "Tmin", "Tmin"
    ), monthID = c(6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L
    )), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")


library(dplyr)

dat  %>%
dplyr::group_by(Year, variable_name) %>% 
dplyr::summarise(variable = sum(value))
```

If I want to average the Tmax and Tmin and sum the rest of the variables, I did this

```
dat %>%        
dplyr::group_by(Year, variable_name) %>% 
dplyr::summarise(variable = ifelse(variable_name %in% c('Tmax', 'Tmin'), mean(value), sum(value)))

Error: Column `variable` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 2
```

How do I correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this is `dplyr` is to use `if` and `else` instead of `ifelse`:

```
dat %>%        
  group_by(Year, variable_name) %>% 
  summarise(variable = if (variable_name[1] %in% c('Tmax', 'Tmin')) mean(value) else sum(value))

# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Year [1]
  Year  variable_name variable
  <chr> <chr>            <dbl>
1 2010  ETo              859. 
2 2010  Rday              39  
3 2010  Rsum             565. 
4 2010  Thdd             102. 
5 2010  Tmax              31.0
6 2010  Tmin              18.7
```

Comment: It just struck me or maybe i missed it, what is the purpose of `variable_name[1] ` instead of doing `variable_name` in your solution?

Comment: `variable name` is a vector which typially will have length greater than one. Therefore `variable_name%in% c('Tmax', 'Tmin')` will return a vector which `if` cannot handle.

Answer (score 2):

I *think* the problem is that `ifelse` in this context is operating row-wise, not at the level of the group. If that's right, then you could work around the problem by getting both summary statistics and then conditionally selecting the one you want by variable name, like this:

```
dat %>%        
dplyr::group_by(Year, variable_name) %>% 
dplyr::summarise(var_mean = mean(value), var_sum = sum(value)) %>%
dplyr::mutate(variable = ifelse(variable_name %in% c('Tmax', 'Tmin'), var_mean, var_sum)) %>%
dplyr::select(-var_mean, -var_sum)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   Year [1]
  Year  variable_name variable
  <chr> <chr>            <dbl>
1 2010  ETo              859. 
2 2010  Rday              39  
3 2010  Rsum             565. 
4 2010  Thdd             102. 
5 2010  Tmax              31.0
6 2010  Tmin              18.7
```